# Node red - use a different port for http input nodes than for the ui

Tags: node-red

I know that you can set the port for the UI in the settings file or by the PORT environment variable, and this is also the port used for "http in" nodes, but how I can specify different ports for these two purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this time you can not run the HTTP-in nodes on a different port as they are all attached to the same instance of ExpressJS as the rest of Node-RED.

Comment: I expected that, thanks for the info. Can I completely disable the UI for a finished product that should not be tampered with?

Comment: Yes, you can disable the editor with the `disableEditor` flag in settings.js

Comment: You can also protect the Editor by settings a username and password if you don't want to totally remove the editor

Answer (score 1):

Node-Red using same instance providing web interface and http endpoints.
Keep in mind it is possible to protect editor with password authentification by uncommenting the **adminAuth** properties in your settings.js file.
HTTPS would be also good idea to enable. [More info about Security](https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/runtime/securing-node-red).
Editor may be disabled for prod instances by **disableEditor** flag in settings.js

Still there are contrib plugins available which allows to change port for HTTP endpoints, example:
https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-http-custom-port